# Javascript and subdivision, crashing browser in for loop

Tags: javascript, geometry, paperjs

I'm working on some generative visuals using paper.js, and the plan is to define a random shape, subdivide it, and then randomize those points as well (to a different degree). Right now, the browser is crashing while attempting to subdivide a polygon.

I'm relatively new to doing these things in Javascript, so maybe I am expecting too much out of it, apparently crashes within intensive for loops are just something that happen. Does anyone have some tips?

```
var Cloud = function(point) {
    this.origin = point;
    this.initBound = new Size(600,200); 
    this.RoM = 40;

    var numsides = 6;
    var scalingFactor = new Point(1,this.initBound.height/this.initBound.width);

    var cloud = new Path.RegularPolygon({
        center: this.origin,
        sides: numsides,
        radius: this.initBound.width/2,
        strokeColor: 'black'
    });

    cloud.scaling = scalingFactor;

    var initBoundBox = new Path.Rectangle({
        point: new Point(point.x-this.initBound.width/2,point.y-this.initBound.height/2),
        size: this.initBound,
        strokeColor: 'red'
    });

    for(var i=0;i<numsides;i++){
        var px = cloud.segments[i].point.x;
        var py = cloud.segments[i].point.y;

        var x = Math.floor(Math.random()*( (px+this.RoM)-(px-this.RoM)+1 ) + (px-this.RoM) );
        var y = Math.floor(Math.random()*( (py+this.RoM)-(py-this.RoM)+1 ) + (py-this.RoM) );

        var tmpP = new Point(x,y);
        cloud.segments[i].point = tmpP;
    }

    for(var i=0;i<cloud.segments.length-1;i++){
        var mdPnt = new Point((cloud.segments[i].point.x+cloud.segments[i+1].point.x)/2,(cloud.segments[i].point.y+cloud.segments[i+1].point.y)/2); 
        cloud.add(i,mdPnt); //breaking here
    }   

    //cloud.smooth();
}

new Cloud(new Point(500,300));
```

Comment: Where exactly does it crash, and does it crash with a message?

Comment: Crashes at cloud.add() in the second for loop. No messages, just brings Firefox to a halt.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your last for-loop, you're adding a segment in each iteration, and thereby increasing cloud.segments.length by one. Your loop never ends. You can mitigate this by incrementing by 2 instead of 1, or finding a better bisection routine.

In short, try this as a starting point:

```
for(var i=0;i<cloud.segments.length-1;i+=2){
    var mdPnt = new Point((cloud.segments[i].point.x+cloud.segments[i+1].point.x)/2,(cloud.segments[i].point.y+cloud.segments[i+1].point.y)/2); 
    cloud.add(i,mdPnt); //breaking here
}
```

Comment: Oh wow, that makes too much sense. Thank you, I'll try it out asap.

Comment: What if I store the value of my initial segment length separately, and continue storing each in an array so I can do multiple levels of bisection?

Comment: There's a lot of ways to get it done, but it's probably easiest to use `curve.divide(parameter)`.